# how to test restful web service with parameters separated by semi colons and requiring authentication using soapui

Tags: rest, authentication, parameters, soapui

I am using SOAP ui's REST services to do a testing. How can i test restful webservice consisting of matrix parameters(with different datatypes) which are seperated by semi colon. This web service also requires authentication

My request looks like this:

http://www.myservice.com/endpoint/parameter1=0309281;parameter2=ABC;parameter3=myemail@email.com;

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add parameters as `MATRIX` to the REST Service.

Try to add a parameter to the REST Service, change the style from `QUERY`(default) to `MATRIX`.

Refer this [snapshot](http://snag.gy/wKgCw.jpg).